# Regex to remove dots from string

Tags: c#, regex

I have this

```
regex Regex.Replace(listing.Company, @"[^A-Za-z0-9_\.~]+", "-");
```

listing.Company is a string, this works but when a string has dots it does not remove them.

Could you please help me out

Comment: Can you provide a sample string, as well as the desired output?

Comment: Input string is Mt. San Pete, i would like it to be mt-san-pete

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
string res = Regex.Replace(listing.Company, @"[\W+\.~]", "-");
```

Here regex engine will look for any character other than `A-Z, a-z, underscore` along with `dot` and `~` and will replace it with "-".

#### [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/9LUxyWGgpa)

Answer (score 2):

In your current regex, you have `\.` in your exclusion, which will cause it to be ignored by `Regex.Replace`. Also, your regex does nothing to convert the input string to lower case. You can do that afterwards, but doing it before your Replace makes your pattern simpler.

Try this method out:

```
var output = Regex.Replace(listing.Company.ToLower(), "[^a-z0-9_]+", "-");
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Regex.Replace(listing.Company.ToLower(), @"[^a-z0-9_]+", "-");
```

you are excluding `\.` which is for dot.
Also, if you want it in lower letters, you need to convert the string to lower case first.